# Using QtWebKit for screenshot - result: white images

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4

I would like to save web page as a PNG image using QtWebKit (pyQt).

I found following code on the internet, but as an output I get white image:

```
import sys
import signal

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebPage

def onLoadFinished(result):
    if not result:
        print "Request failed"
        sys.exit(1)
    # Set the size of the (virtual) browser window
    webpage.setViewportSize(QSize(640,480))

    # Paint this frame into an image
    image = QImage(QSize(640,480), QImage.Format_ARGB32)
    paint = QPainter(image)
    print webpage.mainFrame().toHtml()
    webpage.mainFrame().render(paint)
    paint.end()
    image.save("output.png")
    sys.exit(0)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)

webpage = QWebPage()
webpage.connect(webpage, SIGNAL("loadFinished(bool)"), onLoadFinished)
webpage.mainFrame().load(QUrl("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=640x480&location=50.073723,14.43037&pitch=-0.760&sensor=false&heading=-169.73968469794528"))

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It saves correctly other pages that I've tested, but can't handle Google Street View.

```
print webpage.mainFrame().toHtml()
```

shows that proper web page is loaded, but somehow it doesn't render it... Do you know why?

I use: PyQt4-4.10.2-gpl-Py2.7-Qt4.8.4-x64